# How to draw nanotubes with TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I am working in the field of Nanostructures and have to draw many figure like :
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's generally good to show what you've tried so far... have you looked at the manual for `pst-3d`?

Comment: Considering the solution provided is exactly what you asked for, and extremely well explained, it seems unkind (to say the least) not to accept that answer neither thank him.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}


\begin{document}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubelength}{5} % in "double hexagon lengths"
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubecirumferenceatoms}{12} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tuberadius}{3}
\newcommand{\carboncolor}{red}
\newcommand{\bondcolor}{black}

\tikzset{yzplane/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=#1,very thin}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.2cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
\foreach \x in {1,...,\tubelength}
{ \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+0.5,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+1.5,\ycoord,\zcoord);
    }
    \begin{scope}[yzplane=\x*3+0.5]
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \shade[ball color=\carboncolor] (\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360:\tuberadius) circle (0.2) ;
    }
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordtwo}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordtwo}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotanglethree}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360-360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordthree}{cos(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordthree}{sin(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+1.5,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+2,\ycoordtwo,\zcoordtwo);
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+1.5,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+2,\ycoordthree,\zcoordthree);
    }
    \begin{scope}[yzplane=\x*3+1.5]
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \shade[ball color=\carboncolor] (\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360:\tuberadius) circle (0.2);
    }
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+2,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+3,\ycoord,\zcoord);
    }
    \begin{scope}[yzplane=\x*3+2]
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor] (\rotangle:\tuberadius) circle (0.2);
    }
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordtwo}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordtwo}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotanglethree}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360-360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordthree}{cos(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordthree}{sin(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+3.5,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+3,\ycoordtwo,\zcoordtwo);
        \draw[thick,\bondcolor] (\x*3+3.5,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3+3,\ycoordthree,\zcoordthree);
    }
    \begin{scope}[yzplane=\x*3+3]
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor] (\rotangle:\tuberadius) circle (0.2);
    }
    \end{scope}


}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can modify a few things:

- The length of the tube (multiples of 4 atoms)
- The amount of atoms on one circle
- The radius of the tube
- The color of the atoms
- The color of the bonds

The above produces:

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** If you play around with the settings, e.g. like

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubelength}{20} % in "double hexagon lengths"
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubecirumferenceatoms}{20} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tuberadius}{4}
\newcommand{\carboncolor}{red!80!black}
\newcommand{\bondcolor}{blue!20!black}
```

you get this, which looks a lot "*nanotubier*":

[image]

---

**Edit 2:**

- The "back" atoms now fade to white, the "back" bonds now fade to gray
- As I don't know which atoms will be in the back (depends on your choice of xyz-axes), I added a key `\initialrotationangle` which rotates the tube by that angle, you'll have to find a good value yourself
- Before, the "bondlength" was a static value of 1, which looked bad for small radii, so now it's computed dynamically (it does not account for the curvature of the cylinder, so it might look bad for very small values of `\tubecircumferenceatoms`)
- The atom size also was static before, now you can specify it as a fraction of the bondlength. You can set this fraction to zero to have just the "bond net" without any atoms
- As I computed the coordinates for the bonds anyway, I now compute the ones for the atoms as well and therefore got rid of the `3D` library if `TikZ`
- You can now influence the look of the bonds, e.g. `thin` or `dashed` to your liking

And here's the new code. I'm aware that I have several loops running over `\y`, but I can not put everything in one loop, as their order is important for drawing foreground and background things.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubelength}{10} % in "double hexagon lengths"
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tubecirumferenceatoms}{12} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tuberadius}{3}
\newcommand{\carboncolor}{red}
\newcommand{\bondcolor}{blue}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\initialrotationangle}{270}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\atombondlengthfraction}{0.2}
\newcommand{\bonddrawoptions}{thin}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.2cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=0.5]
\foreach \x in {1,...,\tubelength}
{ \pgfmathsetmacro{\bondlength}{2*3.14159265*\tuberadius/sqrt(3)/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atomradius}{\bondlength*\atombondlengthfraction}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{50*cos(\rotangle+\initialrotationangle)+50}
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+0.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+1.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord);
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor!\shadingcolor] (\x*3*\bondlength+0.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) circle (\atomradius*1cm) ;
    }

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordtwo}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordtwo}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotanglethree}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360-360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordthree}{cos(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordthree}{sin(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{50*cos(\rotangle+\initialrotationangle)+50}
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+1.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+2*\bondlength,\ycoordtwo,\zcoordtwo);
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+1.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+2*\bondlength,\ycoordthree,\zcoordthree);
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor!\shadingcolor] (\x*3*\bondlength+1.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) circle (\atomradius*1cm);
    }

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{50*cos(\rotangle+\initialrotationangle)+50}
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+2*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+3*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord);
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor!\shadingcolor] (\x*3*\bondlength+2*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) circle (\atomradius*1cm);
    }

    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{cos(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoord}{sin(\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordtwo}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordtwo}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotanglethree}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360-360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordthree}{cos(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordthree}{sin(\rotanglethree)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{50*cos(\rotangle+\initialrotationangle)+50}
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+3.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+3*\bondlength,\ycoordtwo,\zcoordtwo);
        \draw[\bonddrawoptions,\bondcolor!\shadingcolor!gray] (\x*3*\bondlength+3.5*\bondlength,\ycoord,\zcoord) -- (\x*3*\bondlength+3*\bondlength,\ycoordthree,\zcoordthree);
    }
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\tubecirumferenceatoms}
    { \pgfmathsetmacro{\rotangle}{\y/\tubecirumferenceatoms*360+360/2/\tubecirumferenceatoms}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoordtwo}{cos(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\zcoordtwo}{sin(\rotangle)*\tuberadius}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\shadingcolor}{50*cos(\rotangle+\initialrotationangle)+50}
        \shade[ball color=\carboncolor!\shadingcolor] (\x*3*\bondlength+3*\bondlength,\ycoordtwo,\zcoordtwo) circle (\atomradius*1cm);
    }

}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And a few samples:

[image]

And just the bonds:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! How about sending it to texample.net?

Comment: Probably, but not yet. It still has several flaws that I want to work out first, and I think I can simplify it quite a bit. So maybe when I'm done.

Comment: I cannot differentiate the front parts from the rear ones. Is it possible to improve this appearance issue?

Comment: I'm working on it. It will fade the color to white for the "back" atoms.

Comment: Absolutely amazing!

Comment: Great! very good idea !!

Comment: Yes, this is even better!