# How to draw an optical lattice

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost, technical-drawing

I want to make in TikZ or MetaPost an image of a two dimensional lattice with oscillations like these:

[image: optical lattice]
[image: another optical lattice]

<sub>(Source: http://www.uibk.ac.at/th-physik/qo/research/opticallattices.html)</sub>

or this one:

[image: yet another optical lattice]

<sub>(Source: http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2008/09/12-01.html)</sub>

I don't know even know how to begin.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vote to close because this question has an open bounty. However I think that your question is off topic. Short version -- *Can you do the job for me*.

Comment: Please don't pile on downvotes. A net score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs to be improved. More downvotes should be reserved for questions that are unsalvageable or spam.

Comment: I don't want that people do the job for me I just want some ideas or which package to use! In fact I tried it alone and I did not find a good and short solution!

Comment: IMHO this is not more or less off topic than [How to draw nanotubes with TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54341/how-to-draw-nanotubes-with-tex)

Answer (score 10):

Here's something to get you (or perhaps someone else) started

[image]

I realize that the balls aren't exactly where you want them, but you can tweak the positions yourself.

The idea was to use a surface plot of the function `f(x,y)=cos(x)*cos(y)` using the `pgfplots` package.

The only subtlety is to loop through the balls, which requires the loop to be wrapped in `\pgfplotsextra{ ... }`.

I borrowed Altermundus' ball shading from [How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/39250#39250)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% borrowed from Altermundus' Christmas tree
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/39250#39250
\newsavebox{\ball}
\savebox{\ball}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1]
 \shadedraw[ball color=red] (0,0) circle (60pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,zmin=-5,zmax=5,colormap/cool]
  \addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=flat,
    samples=50,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
    y domain=-2*pi:2*pi
  ]{cos(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))};
  \pgfplotsextra{
    \foreach \deco in {
        (axis cs:-1,-1,1),
        (axis cs:-2,-2,1),
        (axis cs:3,3,1),
        (axis cs:-3,-3,1),
        (axis cs:4,4,1)
    }{%
        \node at \deco {\usebox{\ball}};
    }
  }
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have the following error:pgfplots@addplotimpl@expression@curly. Any hint?

Comment: @PanAkry make sure your distribution is up to date

Answer (score 4):

I made few modifications in the previous code and got this result:

[image: Hubbard model for an optical lattice]

Here is my version:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2, 0.9}


\newcommand\drawparticle[5]{
    \shadedraw[ball color=#1, draw=none] (axis cs:#2,#3,#4) circle (#5 pt); 
}

\def \radiusparticle{5.5}
\def \zparticle{-0.5}
\def \shiftdoubleoccupation{pi*0.095}

% OBS:
% top view = 90, 90 -> useful if you want to find the positions of particles in xy-plan
% wanted view = 25, 65 -> angles phi and theta that I set for the perspective 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
   [xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,ymin=-2*pi,ymax=2*pi,zmin=-2.5,zmax=2.5,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    view={25}{65},
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
      \addplot3[
        surf,
        samples=50,
        domain=-2.15*pi:2.15*pi,
        y domain=-2.15*pi:2.15*pi,
        shader=interp,
          opacity=0.5
      ]{cos(deg(x))*cos(deg(y))};

    \pgfplotsextra{

    \foreach \ix/\iy in {-2/1,2/1,-2/-1,2/-1}{
        \drawparticle{red}{pi*\ix}{pi*\iy}{\zparticle}{\radiusparticle};
    }     
    \foreach \ix/\iy in {1/0,1/2,1/-2,-1/2,-1/-2}{
        \drawparticle{blue}{pi*\ix}{pi*\iy}{\zparticle}{\radiusparticle};
    }

    \drawparticle{blue}{0-\shiftdoubleoccupation}{-pi+0.5*\shiftdoubleoccupation}{-0.5}{5};
    \drawparticle{red}{0+\shiftdoubleoccupation}{-pi-0.5*\shiftdoubleoccupation}{-0.5}{5};

    \node[] (Coulombcenter) at (axis cs: 0+2*\shiftdoubleoccupation, -pi+2*\shiftdoubleoccupation, 1.0) {};

    \node[anchor=center, align=center, font=\large \rmfamily \bfseries \color{black}, circle, fill=lightgray!70!black, rounded corners=1.0pt, inner sep=4.15pt] (Coulombcircle2) at ($(Coulombcenter.center)+(0,0)$) {\hphantom{$U$}};

    \node[anchor=center, align=center, font=\large \rmfamily \bfseries \color{black}, circle, top color=blue!30!lightgray, bottom color=red!50!lightgray, rounded corners=1.0pt, inner sep=3.75pt] (Coulombcircle) at ($(Coulombcenter.center)+(0,0)$) {\hphantom{$U$}};

    \node[anchor=center, align=center, font=\large \rmfamily \bfseries \color{black}, circle, top color=lightgray!50!white, bottom color=lightgray!50!gray, rounded corners=1.0pt, inner sep=0.25pt] (Coulombtext) at ($(Coulombcenter.center)+(0,0,0)$) {$U$};

    \node[] (hoppingstart) at (axis cs: -pi, 0, \zparticle){};
    \node[] (hoppingend) at (axis cs: 0, pi, \zparticle) {};

    \draw[->,myarrowcontour] ($(hoppingstart.center)+(\radiusparticle,\radiusparticle,0.5*\radiusparticle)$) to node[auto, swap, above, font=\Large \color{white}] {}($(hoppingend.south)+(3.*\radiusparticle,3*\radiusparticle, -2.*\radiusparticle)$);

    \draw[->,myarrow] ($(hoppingstart.center)+(\radiusparticle,\radiusparticle,0.5*\radiusparticle)$) to node[auto, swap, above, font=\Large \color{white}] {\color{black}$t$}($(hoppingend.south)+(2*\radiusparticle,2*\radiusparticle, 1*\radiusparticle)$); 

    \drawparticle{blue}{-pi}{0}{\zparticle}{\radiusparticle};

      }

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where, I defined the arrow styles as

```
    myarrowcontour/.style={lightblue!30!lightgray, >=latex, line width=5pt, bend left=45},
    myarrow/.style={lightblue, >=latex, line width=3.5pt, bend left=45}
```

but changes can improve the final result.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the code. Could you please explain the physics behind the arrow marked by time t and the U with two atoms?