# How I can break a long tikz box in an automatic way?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}



% Define box and box title style
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎
        ‎\begin{itemize}
 ‎\item‎‎
 1‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 2‎‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 1‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 2‎‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 1‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 2‎‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 1‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 2‎‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 1‎
 ‎\item‎‎
 2‎
 \end{itemize} ‎‎
 To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
    \end{minipage}‎

};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {A fancy title};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{document}
```

I want to write a long box (more than one page) by tikz. it is possible that break box automatically?

Comment: Use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) instead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that even though your questions have recieved answers (some of them [`spectacular`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54525/3954)), you still haven't accepted any. You can accept an answer that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954). Please consider accepting best answers to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to produce your box allowing page breaks; here's the translation of your box using `tcolorbox`'s settings (adjust the parameters according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newtcolorbox{myfancybox}[1]{
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=blue!20,
  colframe=red,
  top=12pt,
  overlay unbroken={\node[fill=red,text=white] at (frame.east) {$\clubsuit$};},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=10pt,yshift=-8pt},
  boxed title style={size=small,colback=red,colframe=red},
  title=#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfancybox}{The title}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
\end{myfancybox}

\begin{myfancybox}{The title}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎
        ‎\begin{itemize}
\item Test
 \end{itemize} ‎‎
 To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}‎‎
\end{myfancybox}%


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]