# How to draw a multiwalled carbon nanotubes in Tex/Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following the steps described in the question "How to draw a nanotube in Tex?"in [How to draw nanotubes with TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54341/47927). I would like to know how to insert another nanotube inside the first one? That is, how to draw a multiwalled nanotube as in the attached image.

[image: A Multi-Walled Carbon Nanotube]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome! You could try learning Ti*k*Z: https://tikz.dev/ - the tutorial are really useful and easy to follow.

Comment: Are you referring to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54341/47927)?

Comment: Yes. My friend!

Comment: @FHZ -- That's exactly the same question mentioned in the question, which asks how to add another feature.